# Compiling output files in UNIX

Tags: unix

Simple question perhaps but for some reason finding it tricky to perform.

I am running a programme on UNIX called phon. I want to save all the text created while phon is running, so I have done the following:

phon>out

However, I am now doing a looping sequence of variables and the out file is overwritten for every value. How can I write it so that the out file doesn't get overwritten and instead, simply compiles and grows?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks! And how would I append a particular line of text in the out file?? In this case the line with the word "energy". I assume I would use a grep function in addition to something else.... what would that be??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `>>` as that will append to the file.

Comment: Refer to the bash manual to learn about [redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections)